# Mysql, get back one result (row) at case statement

Tags: mysql, select, case

I need help. I want to get back one result at SELECT statement but I get two. I want that, if there is text at asked language ' get back the text
but
if there is not text at asked language get back the default language text WHERE 'text_id =  1'

```
textlang
lang_id  text_id  text
1        1        EnglishText
2        1        SpanishText

my code:
SELECT text FROM textlang Where text_id ='1' 
and 
CASE lang_id 
WHEN 'asked_language' THEN lang_id = 'asked_language'  
ELSE lang_id ='default language' 
END
```

if I select Spanish language, this code give back both English and Spanish text . I need only one result back.
any idea?
Thanks!

the database schema

```
CREATE TABLE lang(
ID INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
LangCode char 5,
LangName nvarchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE text(
text_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE textlang(
textlang_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
lang_id INT,
text_id INT,
text varchar(150),
FOREIGN KEY(lang_id) REFERENCES lang(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(text_id) REFERENCES text(text_id)
);
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: You need to provide more info about your DB schema. As @Strawberry mentioned, create a SQL fiddle.

Comment: I wrote the database schema to my question now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(r.text, d.text) AS text
FROM
  (SELECT text
  FROM textlang
  WHERE text_id = 1 AND lang_id = @requestedLanguage) AS r,
  (SELECT text
  FROM textlang
  WHERE text_id = 1 AND lang_id = @defaultLanguage) AS d;
```

More about it [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php).

I have not tried it I'm writing off the top of my head so test it first, it might not work as expected...

Comment: I've tried this in a sqlfiddle and it doesn't work. I leave it here for reference but it is clearly wrong.

Comment: The COALESCE() function give back null if asked language not exists and default language exists.

Comment: If somebody have any idea please wirte me. I should request both language and then search between the result but it would be better if I should request the good data from mysql. Thanks,